# How do I change the name of CakePHP root directory

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to change the name of the root directory of a CakePHP install.  For example the root is called 'CakePHP_Website' and I want to change it to 'My_Website'.

However when I rename the directory I get the following error:

```
Missing Controller
Error: MyWebsiteController could not be found.

Error: Create the class MyWebsiteController below in file: app\Controller\MyWebsiteController.php
```

What is the process for achieving this?

Comment: Use [vhost setup](http://www.dereuromark.de/tag/virtual-host/) - then you would not need to rename any directory, and all would work out of the box (routing directly into the webroot).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I see what you are saying. However I kind of had my heart set on knowing how to rename the directory itself without CakePHP breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is frustratingly simple.  CakePHP urls are case sensitive.  So when change the root directory to 'My_Website' and then type in 'localhost/my_website' this will throw an error.  Instead I have to type in 'localhost/My_Website' and this will work just fine.

Comment: yes that is the reason I try to avoid any capital letters in file or folder names. Nothing but trouble. Also with image names.

Answer (score 0):

in `/app/webroot/index.php` to `/app/My_Website/index.php` add these lines:

```
define('WWW_ROOT', '/full/path/to/My_Website/');
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'My_Website');
```

Comment: So are you saying that I need to rename my webroot directory to 'My_Website' as well if I rename the top level root directory to 'My_Website'.  Then add those two define statements to match the newly renamed webroot dir?

Answer (score 0):

If My_Website is your app folder and otherwise you have a default installation then you can change the .htaccess in your installation to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ My_Website/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) My_Website/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However you will never have to rename the webroot folder in your app.

Or do you want to move the core?
Your question was not completely clear to me, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for posting, it's appreciated.  I was however referring to the top level directory which houses the CakePHP app.  So it would be WWW/My_Website/app.